# ReactJS function isn't getting latest state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying out ReactJS, but am running into difficulty incorporating it into my form. I'm building out an auto-suggest form in ReactJS. In my `onChangeQuery`, I'm setting the state and then calling out to an AJAX function to grab suggestions from my server-side code; however, I've noticed that the 
`loadGroupsFromServer` function isn't getting the latest state... It's one key stroke too slow. I know `setState` isn't instantaneous, but then why would I ever use `setState` for my forms? Is it better to use refs? Better to just get the value from `e.target.value`?

Help!

```
  var GroupForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {query: "", groups: []}
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
      this.loadGroupsFromServer();
    },
    loadGroupsFromServer: function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: this.props.url,
        data: {q: this.state.query},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (groups) {
          this.setState({groups: groups});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },
    onChangeQuery: function(e) {
      this.setState({query: e.target.value})
      this.loadGroupsFromServer();
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <form class="form form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.query} placeholder="Search for groups" onChange={this.onChangeQuery} />
            </div>
          </form>
          <GroupList groups={this.state.groups} />
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
```

Comment: if you call setState yourself, you shouldn’t expect this.state to be updated immediately.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`setState` takes a callback which allows you to ensure `this.loadGroupsFromQuery()` is called only after `this.state` is updated.

```
this.setState({...}, function() {
  this.loadGroupsFromQuery();
});
```

Comment: I did the same but still its is not upto the expectation. Its is toooo slow. Any other hacks to improve it ?

Comment: @DEEPANKUMAR what is slow, do you remember if getting to the callback is slow or if the `loadGroupsFromQuery` call is slow

Comment: forget about the loadGroupsFromQuery() function, just do console.log() or anyother simple function to check the speed of state update speed. The local state update duration is too long.

Answer (score 18):

**setState Best Practice**

**ES5**

```
this.setState(function(state, props){
   return {
      query: e.target.value
   }
}, function()=>{
   //after callback 
});
```

**ES6**

```
 this.setState((state, props) => ({
    query: e.target.value
 }), ()=>{
   //after callback 
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

loadGroupsFromServer should take a query argument.

```js
componentDidMount: function () {
  this.loadGroupsFromServer(this.state.query);
},
loadGroupsFromServer: function (query) {
  $.ajax({
    /* ... */
    data: {q: query},
    /* ... */
  });
},
onChangeQuery: function(e) {
  this.setState({query: e.target.value})
  this.loadGroupsFromServer(e.target.value);
},
```

You should generally try to reduce access to state because it gives you more flexibility.

Depending on the case you may want to wait for the component to update before performing some action:

```js
onChangeQuery: function(e) {
  this.setState({query: e.target.value}, function(){
      this.loadGroupsFromServer(this.state.query)
  }.bind(this));
},
```

Or you could rewrite it like this, which is cleaner in my opinion.

```js
onChangeQuery: function(e) {
  this.setState({query: e.target.value});
},
componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState){
  // optionally perform better heuristics, but this prevents them pressing space
  // from triggering an update
  if (nextState.query.trim() !== this.state.query.trim()) {
      this.loadGroupsFromServer(nextState.query);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The root cause of your one-character off problem was that you were reading state before it was set. setState is fast, but it's not instant and synchronous. The previous answers provide you a couple ways to refactor.

Answer (score 5):

setState is not slow, but it is asynchronous. So as per answer above it will work synchronously whever your state is set.

As per the best practice state should be set outsite of the render method.