# set state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this state variable on my react component:

```
this.state = {
  application: {
    institutions: [{
     "name":null
    }]
  }
}
```

I want to set the state of the variable name and what I did was this:

```
handleChangeInstitution(event,indexInstitution){

    const institutions = [...this.state.application.institutions]

    institutions[indexInstitution] = {
        ...institutions[indexInstitution],
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        application: {
            ...prevState.application,
            institutions: [
                ...institutions,
            ]
        }
    }))

}
```

This works just fine but it is really slow when I am typing something on my input box.
Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: Check out these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176838/reactjs-setstate-is-slow and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833126/react-setstate-slow

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner solution. Plus, this is a very common pattern of updating array items. About the performance, there is nothing you can do about it from this part of the code. It should not be about this part.

```
handleChangeInstitution(event,indexInstitution){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        application: {
            ...prevState.application,
            institutions: [
                ...institutions.slice(0, indexInstitution),
                {
                  ...institutions[indexInstitution],
                  [event.target.name]: event.target.value
                },
                ...institutions.slice(indexInstitution + 1),
            ]
        }
    }))

}
```